# DC.js - How do I get my bar chart rect width identical using dc.time.months?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have slightly different widths of bars in DC. I've made many barCharts before without this problem. From googling, it might be relevant the dataset is >10k rows. See how the 2nd and 3rd bars are too close? Using .gap etc doesn't help.

[image: dc.js barChart with varying widths]

The  elements have the same width attribute in the DOM (e.g. 14) but when I hover over one in the DOM, the element on the page is shown to have a slightly bigger width (e.g. 14.0166). These widths vary. I'm using .xUnits(d3.time.months) but the bar widths don't seem thinner on shorter months (e.g. February). I've tried setting .xUnits() with a function returning e.g. 10, but the bars all then end up very wide (e.g. 36) and overlap. I've tried it with function() and more elaborate parameters as per documentation:

```
.xUnits(function(start,end,xDomain){ return 10; });
```

I've also tried a renderlet using d3 to get the widths the same, but it has no effect - presumably because the widths ARE the same already, according to the DOM. My theory is that the problem is the long decimals of the x position of each bar.

I know there is a related bug that was due for fix in version 2. I'm using 2.1 and browser = FF v 45. I know it's only aesthetic but if anyone knows a fix please help!

I have d3 graphics on the same page with no similar problems. However I want to use dc.js for this time widget to get all the brush behaviours.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I think the implementation is fundamentally wrong - a bar width constant is calculated and then bars are drawn at the exact dates, which vary in distance from each other. AFAIK the only solution with current dc.js is to use a linear scale instead (map dates to month numbers and then set the axis [tickFormat](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#tickFormat) to print the numbers as dates). Put differently, using a d3 time scale doesn't make sense if you want the bars the same width - dc.js would have to support variable bar widths to work correctly with it.